# Rellenar combobox con php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery

Estamos realizando un sistema de registro de mascotas, en el módulo de editar datos se debe llenar un combobox con los datos esterilizados Si o No, para que se llene ese combobox se hace una consulta a la tabla esterilizado, pero dicha tabla está relacionada con la tabla mascotas, quiere decir que al momento de registrar la mascota se inserta de ID de esterilizado, lo que queremos es que al momento de hacer la consulta se debe llenar el combobox con los datos de esterilizado y con id  que se registró en mascota

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="esterelizadoMascota">Esterelizado</label>
               <select class="form-control" id="esterelizadoMascota">                                       
                    <?php
                        $sqlestado = "SELECT * FROM esterelizado";
                           $consultaEstado = $conexion->query($sqlestado);
                                   while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($consultaEstado)) {
                                     echo "<option value='" .
                                       $valores['idesterelizado'] .
                                       "'>" .
                                       $valores['estado'] .
                                       "</option>";
                                   }
                                   ?>
                                 </select>
                               </div>
                              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Faltan verificaciones en tu código:

- ¿Hay conexión?
- ¿Es exitosa la consulta?
- ¿Trae filas la consulta?

Son tres posibilidades que no quedan cubiertas. No se puede programar pensando que no hay espinas. Así que se requiere rigor en el código, evaluando todas las posibilidades.

Prueba de este modo y dinos el resultado:

```
<?php
    if ($conexion) {
        $sqlestado = "SELECT * FROM esterelizado";
        if ($consultaEstado = $conexion->query($sqlestado)) { 
            if ($consultaEstado->num_rows > 0) {
            ?>          
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="esterelizadoMascota">Esterelizado</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="esterelizadoMascota">                                       
            <?php
                        while ($valores = $consultaEstado->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo "<option value=\"$valores[idesterelizado]\">$valores[estado]</option>";
                        }   
            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php

            } else {
                echo "No se encontraron datos"; 
            }                              
        } else { 
            echo "Error en la consulta: {$conexion->error}";
        }
    } else {
        echo "No hay conexión activa";
    }
?>
```

Comment: El problema es al llamar al id de la tabla mascota te dejo el código sql para que me comprendas  SELECT m.esterelizado_idesterelizado, e.estado FROM mascota m
  INNER JOIN esterelizado e ON m.esterelizado_idesterelizado = e.idesterelizado, alli estoy capturando si esta esterilizado o no y el id en la tabla mascotas.